# Java equivalent to WCF Data Services

Tags: java, wcf, spring, rest, wcf-data-services

Is there anything in Java that's the equivalent of WCF Data Services ?

Does Spring have the capabilities to expose databases as a RESTful web service like WCF Data Services ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate capabilities - database access and REST web services - but Spring indeed has both.

You can access databases in Spring using JDBC, Hibernate, TopLink, or iBatis.

You can expose web services as SOAP using Spring web services or RESTful web services using [Spring 3.x](http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=54).

You can put the two together to achieve your stated goal.

Comment: I know Spring has the capability to do both things separately but i was wondering if there's a tool that does what "WCF Data Services" does.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Java/Spring tend to be less wizard-like.